# Recaptcha and Web API - Good REST practice to validate the token

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I've got a series of Web API controllers which return data to be consumed by an AngularJS front end.

I'm concerned that it would be super-easy to script a bot that just hammers it with calls and extracts all the data out of my database. Whilst the information is freely available, it took me many hours/weeks/months/years to collate it all - it's really the whole USP of my site. If someone stole my data just by extracting it from the services, I'd be upset.

Simply adding `Authorize` won't help, because it's free to register.

I've decided that I'll submit some sort of token with each request to the API which will get validated. Primarily this will be a solved Captcha, but it could vary in the future so I'm making it extensible. Therefore I'm sending a token type and the token value in a "?token=TypeID,TokenValue" parameter with a type converter to pick this up and turn it into the Token object.

So my question is - *What is good practice to send a token along with a request to a Web API controller? I've done it as follows, is this right? I've read that it's not very RESTful to send a querystring to do the authentication - but it works really well.*

**Sample proof-of-concept**

My controller:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Get(WebApiToken token, int id)
        {
            if (token == null)
                return BadRequest("Token not supplied");


            ITokenValidator requestValidator;

            // Some kind of a factory to decide how to validate the token that's been provided.
            requestValidator = new GuidTokenValidator();

            if (requestValidator.ValidateToken(token))
            {
                return Ok(string.Format("Some JSON would be returned here representing product ID {0}", id));
            }
            else
                return BadRequest("Token validation failed");
        }
    }
```

Javascript to invoke it:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#postTest").click(function () {

               $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   dataType: "json",
                   url: "/api/Products/2?token=2,OK",
                   success: function (data) {
                       alert(data);
                   },
                   error: function (error) {
                       // Error handler
                   }
               });
           });
       });
    </script>
```

The token definition:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(TokenConverter))]
    public class WebApiToken : IToken
    {
        public TokenType TokenType { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }

        public static bool TryParse(string s, out WebApiToken result)
        {
            result = null;

            var parts = s.Split(',');
            if (parts.Length != 2)
            {
                return false;
            }

            int tokenTypeId;

            if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out tokenTypeId))
            {
                result = new WebApiToken() { TokenType = (TokenType)tokenTypeId, Token = parts[1] };
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Type converter:

```
public class TokenConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Type sourceType)
        {
            if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            if (value is string)
            {
                WebApiToken token;
                if (WebApiToken.TryParse((string)value, out token))
                {
                    return token;
                }
            }

            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }
    }
```

Fiddler request:

```
GET http://localhost:58106/api/Products/2?token=2,OK HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:58106 Connection: keep-alive Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36 Referer: http://localhost:58106/ Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

Fiddler response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcYmVuLnNsb2FuXGRvY3VtZW50c1x2aXN1YWwgc3R1ZGlvIDIwMTNcUHJvamVjdHNcV2ViQVBJQWN0aW9uRmlsdGVyc1xXZWJBUElBY3Rpb25GaWx0ZXJzXGFwaVxQcm9kdWN0c1wy?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 20 May 2015 11:59:55 GMT
Content-Length: 60

"Some JSON would be returned here representing product ID 2"
```

Comment: *"I've read that it's not very RESTful to send a querystring to do the authentication*" - what they were probably getting at there is that RESTful URLs are usually [semantically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) styled. However, that's for describing *resources*, in your case the token is *contextual* information and therefore a query string (at least in my opinion) is absolutely fine. However, a cleaner approach would be to send the token up as a header, that way it doesn't impact your URLs at all (considering the token doesn't really relate to the resource).

Comment: @James Thanks for the input. Appreciate it.

Comment: In addition to setting up the token in the header, it would be good to encrypt the token.  Even better would be to set up OAuth2 or something harder for a malicious app to duplicate the request.  If you're using .NET 4.5 - look into OWIN and Claims Based authentication.